# Pip cannot find a specific version of VTK package although it is in PyPI

Tags: python, pip, installation, pypi

I accidentally installed VTK 9.0.0, but want to downgrade to 8.1.2.

I uninstalled VTK 9.0.0 using `pip uninstall` but now I cannot install 8.1.2 for a weird unknown reason:

```
$ pip install "vtk==8.1"
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk==8.1 (from versions: 9.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk==8.1
```

The version 8.1 is definitely in PyPI. Why pip complaints and does not the needed operation?

Comment: Which OS and version of Python is being used?  By issuing the command `pip install "vtk==8.1"` implies the installation of `vtk==8.1.0`, and due to the lack of source releases, wheels are only available for specific OS platforms and Python versions, which are 2.7, and 3.4 to 3.6 inclusive.  If using Python 3.7 no prebuilt wheels are available for that version.

Comment: Moreover, if you really want to downgrade to 8.1.2 you will need to issue the command `pip install "vtk==8.1.2"` instead; that version has the prebuilt wheels for Python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in using Python 3.8. The thing is that neither pip error messages nor PyPI webpages make it very simple to see that the package is not compatible with Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on @metatoaster's comment.

In this case, `pip` could not find VTK 8.1 because the package `VTK` is not available for Python 3.8 for versions < 9.0, while I used Python 3.8.